# Cannot delete MySQL trigger. Appears in information_schema, but no .TRN file

Tags: mysql, trigger, myisam, windows, mysql-5.0

I have a MySQL database with a few tables and triggers. A process was trying to drop one of the triggers and it failed with the following error:

```
Malformed file type header in file 'trigger_name.TRN'
```

I tried to drop the trigger manually, but obviously got the same error. So I went ahead and deleted the `.TRN` file itself (was that a bad idea?).

After deleting the `.TRN` file, the trigger still appears in `information_schema.TRIGGERS`. If I try to drop it I get error "Trigger does not exist". If I try to create another trigger with the same name, table and event manipulation I get error "Trigger already exists".

I don't know what else to do. How can I really delete this trigger so that it can be created again?

MySQL version is 5.0.22 and all tables are MyISAM.

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` outputs:

```
CREATE TABLE `cash_operation` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `amount` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL default '0.00000000',
  `comment` varchar(500) NOT NULL default '',
  `reason_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '-1',
  `date` datetime NOT NULL default '1980-01-01 00:00:00',
  `reconciliation_number` int(11) NOT NULL default '-1',
  `reason_desc` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
  `automatic` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '-1',
  `employee_code` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
  `employee_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
  `payed_employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '-1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `cash_operation_reason_id` USING BTREE (`reason_id`),
  KEY `cash_operation_reconciliation_number` USING BTREE (`reconciliation_number`),
  KEY `cash_operation_automatic` USING BTREE (`automatic`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

`SELECT @@global.datadir;` results in error "Unkown system variable 'datadir'"

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname\G` and post it in the question.

Comment: Please run `SELECT @@global.datadir;`

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA updated post. But I don't see any reference to the trigger in the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: Please run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';`

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA it shows the variable `datadir`, whose value certainly is the path to the data directory of the database.

Comment: Linux or Windows ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Windows

Comment: Run the following `CREATE TABLE cash_op LIKE cash_operation;`. Go to the folder where `cash_op.MYD` is. Do you see a `cash_op.TRN` ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25193/discussion-between-abl-and-rolandomysqldba).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [suggestion I gave in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25193/discussion-between-abl-and-rolandomysqldba), here is my answer

1. `CREATE TABLE cash_op LIKE cash_operation;`
2. Goto the datadir in your Windows server
3. `rename cash_op.MYD cash_op.MYX`
4. `copy cash_operation.MYD cash_op.MYD`
5. login to mysql and run

   - `REPAIR TABLE cash_op;`
   - `ALTER TABLE cash_operation RENAME cash_op_old;`
   - `ALTER TABLE cash_op RENAME cash_operation;`
6. Go create the two triggers on the new cash_operation table

You said in the chat room : `Awesome, that worked! You can post it as the answer.`

**I am glad you gave it a try and it worked for you !!!**

BTW you can drop the old table with `DROP TABLE cash_op_old;`

Comment: 7. Switch to InnoDB so you won't have to run `REPAIR` again.